# Catch the error which stops the execution of my Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, error-handling

I am trying to catch the error that stops the execution of my python script. But I don't want to catch all the errors or exception because some of them are not affecting the success of my scripts they are just guidance or console Info. I only want to catch and stock in a variable the error that cause my python script to stop.
Thanks by advance

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html.

Comment: I'm concerned that you mean something other than "exceptions" when you way "error", because it's not normal to raise an exception just to display "guidance or console info". You should use exceptions for errors, and use print/logging for info. You can catch an exception but you can't catch a print call.

Comment: What's the output when you run your script? Without seeing the traceback we can't help you much here.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
try:
   code where my error occurs
except:
   pass
```

Comment: Wouldn't this catch all errors? OP wanted to be able to catch only specific errors.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small example on how to catch a specific error. Let's say you would want to check if a `ZeroDivisionError` is raised:

```
a = 3
b = 0

try:
    _ = a/b
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Running the above code snippet would result  in:
`division by zero`

Comment: Thank you for you answer but unfortunately I don't know exaclty yet the kind of errors which can happen so I don't want to be specific. I want to catch every possible errors that stops the execution of my script.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly then. It seems to me, upon reading your question, that you would like to be able to catch specific errors and act accordingly based on what error occurred.